# spaCy cannot find method add_label for EntityRecognizer class in python

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I want to update the entity recognizer in spaCy with an own example. After getting the instance of the Named Entity Recognizer pipeline component I want to call the method `add_label()` on it:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
ner = nlp.get_pipe('ner')
ner.add_label()
```

I cannot call `add_label()`, because it `Cannot find reference 'add_label' in 'Pipe | Pipe`. I first thought that `add_label()` might be deprecated in spaCy v3, but the [docs](https://spacy.io/api/entityrecognizer#add_label) implies that it is not. The pipeline also includes the `ner` component:

```
print(nlp.pipe_names)
output: ['tok2vec', 'tagger', 'parser', 'attribute_ruler', 'lemmatizer', 'ner']
```

Further informations:

- spaCy version 3.4.3
- Pipelines en_core_web_sm (3.4.1)
- Python version 3.10.4

Does anyone have an idea why I cannot call `add_label()` on the `EntityRecognizer`?

Update: Seems to be a problem with **PyCharm (17.0.5+1-b653.14 x86_64)**. Cannot reproduce the issue using **VS Code**.

Comment: Hi, I tried the example and I get the following error: `TypeError: add_label() takes exactly one argument (0 given)` which makes sense as it requires one parameter.
Could you double check the spacy version used with `print(spacy.__version__)`? Thanks

Comment: Thank you for investigating my issue. I double checked my spaCy version and it is 3.4.3. What model did you load and what version of Python did you use to reproduce my issue? Did you use the same code snippet as I did? As you said, it makes sense that you get `TypeError: add_label() takes exactly one argument (0 given)` while calling the method when no argument was provided. But in my case, it seems that the method doesn't exist at all, which is quite strange.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the exact code you provided with Python version 3.10.4. I installed the model using `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` (it may be worth trying to reinstall it).
I even tested with a clean environment and I don't get your error message. I'd suggest to try out setting up a new environment using conda or similar and try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Same issue with fresh environment (PyCharm). No issue using VS Code. Although I still get `Cannot find reference 'add_label' in 'Pipe | Pipe'` on `add_label()` with PyCharm, running the code works. Seems to be a problem of PyCharm.